# Error with: cucumber features -n command

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Rspec book says to run `cucumber features -n` command. But it is giving following error

```
missing argument: -n (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
/Users/pajama/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-    1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb:119:in `parse!'
/Users/pajama/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:25:in `parse!'
/Users/pajama/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:55:in `configuration'
/Users/pajama/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:63:in `run_drb_client'
/Users/pajama/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
/Users/pajama/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/pajama/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pajama/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/Users/pajama/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
/Users/pajama/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/pajama/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the cucumber source:

```
opts.on("-n NAME", "--name NAME",
        "Only execute the feature elements which match part of the given name.",
        "If this option is given more than once, it will match against all the",
        "given names.")
```

so you would need to call `-n name_of_the_feature`

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to do?! if you want to run all the features, just skip this option!